# Start Windows Service programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am having an issue with an application that I am creating.  I am trying to start a windows service through my C# app.  When I click my start button, it looks like everything goes through but when I log into the server, the service still does not show that it is running.  However, the second time I run it, I get an exception that says the instance of the service is already running.  Again when I log into the server, the service appears to be stopped.  Has anyone ever seen this?

Here is my code.

```
try
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        int timeoutMilliseconds = 1000;
        string serviceName = reader["ServiceName"].ToString();
        string permission = reader["Permission"].ToString();

        if (permission == "E")
        {
            lblServStartSuccess.Visible = true;

            ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
            TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

            service.Start();
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
        }
        else
        {
            lblServErrorStart.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.ToString());
}
```

**EDIT:** Here is the exception I received on one service:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Service Logical Disk Manager
>   Administrative Service was not found on computer '.'. --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified service does not
>   exist as an installed service --- End of inner exception stack trace

I know the service exists. Do I need to add something in front of the service to tell it what server to look at?

Comment: Are you sure the service isn't stuck in the starting state? I remember the services control panel wasn't brilliant about showing that (at least some windows version ago)

Comment: what do you mean with "when I log into the server" - are you trying to use the SCM on a different machine?

Comment: Yes I am running the web service from a remote server.  I am using an account that has admin access.  I am not sure if it is stuck.  Could my timeout be too short and it is timing out?

Comment: Oh and both systems in question are running Server 2003.

Comment: 1 second is pretty short for a remote service start.  Change it to 60 seconds and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I removed the timeout and same issue.  Everything appears to be working.  The service just does not show as Started.

Comment: This might be stating the obvious, but are you sure the service you are trying to start is installed on the machine which you are trying to start it on?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If the code you showed is executing on a different machine than where the service is supposed to run (I'm not clear from your comments if that's the case or not), you would need to provide the machine name in the ServiceController constructer.

Is it possible you are successfully starting the service, but not on the machine you think? That would fit the symptoms you describe.

```
ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName, serverName);
```

[Also see `ServiceController` constructor documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.-ctor#System_ServiceProcess_ServiceController__ctor_System_String_System_String_).

Comment: I've edited to show the use of the constructor that takes the remote server name.

Comment: I think you were correct because now I am getting an error saying that other privileges are required to do this.

Comment: If I log in as the impersonated user to the source server, I can pull up the service manager of the target server and remotely start and stop services.  I just can't do it from the web app.

Comment: It may depend on how you have your web app security set up, but I think the account the web app's app pool is running under will need rights to start/stop services on the machine where the services are to be run.

Comment: I had commented out my impersonation.  I need to pay more attention.  Works great now.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 21):

Here is code I have in a Window Service responsible for stopping starting other services running on the same server.

```
ServiceController controller = new ServiceController(serviceName);
if (controller.Status==ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
    controller.Stop();

if (controller.Status==ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
    controller.Start();
```

Answer (score 8):

This is an old thread, but google got me here. My services, even after successfully starting, would still query back as stopped.
If you add

```
service.Refresh();
```

It will query the actual current status instead of the stored state from a previous query. I don't know why it works like this, but it does.

P.S.: I added a minute long time out and still got a service is stopped response without the refresh.

Answer (score 7):

```
public static void StartService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
    {
        ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
        try
        {
            int millisec1 = 0;
            TimeSpan timeout;

            // count the rest of the timeout
            int millisec2 = Environment.TickCount;
            timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds - (millisec1));
            service.Start();
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
    public static void StopService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
    {
        ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
        try
        {
            int millisec1 = 0;
            TimeSpan timeout;
            if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
            {
                millisec1 = Environment.TickCount;
                timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);
                service.Stop();
                service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
            }


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
    public static void RestartService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
    {
        ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
        try
        {
            int millisec1 = 0;
            TimeSpan timeout;
            if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
            {
                millisec1 = Environment.TickCount;
                timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);
                service.Stop();
                service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
            }
            // count the rest of the timeout
            int millisec2 = Environment.TickCount;
            timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds - (millisec2 - millisec1));
            service.Start();
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Dont forget to add ServiceProcess as referance
using System.ServiceProcess;

Comment: Does that add anything to the code in the question?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to add reference of the DLL (ServiceProcess) in your project **References** as like:

```
Right click on References in Solution Explorer -> Add Reference -> Assemblies -> 
Framework -> System.ServiceProcess
```

Then add ServiceProcess DLL in your project:

```
using System.ServiceProcess;
```

After that use this code:

```
ServiceController service = new ServiceController(yourServiceName);
```

Comment: From the code in the question I think the OP had already got past that point.

Answer (score 0):

Just try service.Start(); without the timeout or waitforstatus and hook its events to see whats happening.

Comment: Everything looks to be working.  It just does not show the service as running.