# how to run pre existing windows service using c#

Tags: c#, wpf, service

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# start Windows Service programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667799/c-sharp-start-windows-service-programmatically)

I want to start/stop a preexisting windows service from inside of wpf application . Any pointers on how to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) class and more specifically the [Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb9w7ytd.aspx)/[Stop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.stop.aspx) methods.

Comment: +1 for I have been looking for similar class for sometime

Answer (score 0):

```
Process.Start("net start myService");
```