# How to restart Windows service programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows-services, restart

Used `ServiceController` to start my Windows service from a Windows Form application. But this is not working.

```
ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
```

This statement not working.

Is there any other way to start Windows service from my application.

```
Service Display Name: Duress Alert Service
Service Name: Service1
```

How I can restart my service in C#?

### Edit 1

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb9w7ytd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from below answer:

```
ServiceController sc  = new ServiceController();
sc.ServiceName = "Service1";
```

It shows red line under `ServiceName` and error:

> ServiceController does not contains the definition of ServiceName. No extension method 'ServiceName' no accepting a first argument of type controller could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

While I have added the reference of service process:

```
using System.ServiceProcess;
```

But it still showing the error.

Comment: `ServiceController` works.

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`?  Show the exception.

Comment: There is something fishy going on with this user https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667799/c-sharp-start-windows-service-programmatically/51109413#51109413 You answered a question on this yesterday then pasted your answer as a question today

Comment: @TheGeneral yes I have posted that answer related to adding reference how is that answer is same to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the `Start` and `Stop` methods.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb9w7ytd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for an example.

Comment: It show red line error under `sc.ServiceName` after creating `ServiceController`. That's ServiceController does not contains the definition of `ServiceName`